# Hierarchical thread structure ( thread within threads)

Tags: c#, multithreading, hierarchical

As my topic states I would like to create an hierarchical approach to threading.

I made a picture to help explain. The THREAD in the blue block should create 2 other child threats.

I need to create such a dependency that if my main thread was to be aborted, my child threads should also be aborted.

Also if another blue block with a higher priority takes execution, I want the child threads of the blue block to also go into the wait state.

Also the blue block thread will only be finished if all the child threads are finished and itself.

[image]

Does anyone have any recommendations on this idea?

Comment: This doesn't feel right (even if you could pull it off). Can you explain a bit about the underlying requirements? - e.g. why would a thread be aborted?

Comment: If a thread is interrupted, all of its child threads should be put in the WAIT state

Comment: My recommendation is to forget this plan and redesign so it is avoided.

Comment: You should never call `Thread.Abort()` unless you are trying to crash out of an app. Calling abort can leave the run-time in an invalid state that can affect the remaining threads and hence your entire program. How are you "aborting" threads?

Comment: Can you also explain the computations that you're trying to do with the hierarchy? I suspect that there is alternative approach that would suffice.

Comment: @PigSpdr I would look into green thrads and coroutines, and only use real threads for parallelization of work loads and for wrapping blocking IO.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest requirement to address is the last one:

> Also the blue block thread will only be finished if all the child
>   threads are finished and itself.

You would simply join on the child threads to make this happen.

As to your other requirements, however, your problem is that there is no parent-child relationship between threads. Once one thread kicks another thread off, the two threads are peers. Therefore you cannot rely on the operating system or the framework to establish the hierarchy you're looking for. You will need to implement it yourself, possibly through some kind of a signaling mechanism, where the parent thread, or some controller thread, kills the other threads.

You are likely better off, however, re-architecting your application so it doesn't need this thread hierarchy in place. Think about why you think you need it and in what other ways you can accomplish the same thing -- perhaps structure your data in a hierarchical fashion, and have each thread operate only on the data assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into green threading.

A simple approach would be to design a tree that describes the work tasks, and a thread pool proportional in size to the three, to consume work tasks off the tree and report the results back to handlers specified in the tree.

Such implementation would amout to a coroutines engine essentially.